# Android - How to find methods for my API level

Tags: android

I need to know how to look up which method to use for my API level. Let me give you an example to make it clearer what I need:

I am using API level 16 for my project.
I have a TimePicker called picker. I need to get the hour from picker. I tried using this code: `picker.getHour()` but Android studios tells me that method is API level 23 and above only.

I am guessing that I will run into problems by using this method, so I figured maybe there's an earlier method I can use instead. I found `picker.getCurrentHour()` but Android Studios tells me it's deprecated.

Now I need to know HOW to find out which method to use. (I don't want to come here and ask every single time I run into the same problem in the future.) I guess what I need is a lesson in how to read and understand the documentation.

Comment: just add this tag to that method @TargetApi(23) then u can use it

Comment: unfortunately, correct way is to use `if current android version is >= 23 {use new method} else { use old method }`

Answer (score 0):

Check Build version then invoke the  method based on the version

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) 
picker.getHour();
else 
picker.getCurrentHour();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach by version checking:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ) 
    myTimePickerView.getHour();
else 
    myTimePickerView.getCurrentHour();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check version by Build.VERSION.SDK_INT

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 ) {
  //Code for 23
}
else {
   //Code for below 23
}
```

But I don't face any dependency problem for TimePicker. This is my sample code:

```
import android.widget.TimePicker;
public class YourClass implements  TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

    public void showTimeDialog(){
      new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity())).show();
    }

@Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        //this is your hourOfDay, minute
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use TimePickerDialog?

```
private void onStartTimeClicked() {
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                calendarStart.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                calendarStart.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                startTime.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(activity, calendarStart.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME));
                fitness.setStart(calendarStart.getTime());
            }
        };

        new TimePickerDialog(activity, R.style.MyDatePickerTrain, mTimeListener,
                calendarStart.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                calendarStart.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();
    }
```